# Distributing 11 socks into 4 drawers, with 5 red socks and 6 blue socks.

Tags: combinatorics

This is a problem I thought of while learning combinatorics, so it may be missing something.

You have 11 socks (5 red socks and 6 blue socks) and 4 drawers. What is the number of ways that you can distribute 11 socks into 4 drawers?

Now when I do this I thought of using the following formula
$$ x_1 + x_1' + x_2 + x_2' + x_3 + x_3' + x_4 + x_4' = 11 $$
with the primed ones being the number of blue socks in each drawer (there are four, hence the numbering) and the others being the number of red socks in each drawer. Then I impose the following conditions:
$ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \leq 5 $ and $ x_1' ,x_2', x_3', x_4' \leq 6 $.

But then  I remember that $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 5 $ and $ x_1' + x_2' + x_3' + x_4' = 6 $. There is a formula that counts the number of ways to distribute k objects into n boxes, which can be used in this situation: $$ \binom{n + k - 1}{k} $$

By the product rule I can just arrive at the solution:
$$ \binom{4 + 5 - 1}{5} \cdot \binom{4 + 6 - 1}{6} = 4704 $$

So is the problem well-defined? Is the solution above correct? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the problem into two parts, then multiply the results. Distribute the 5 red socks into 4 drawers.

$$ n_R = C(n+k-1,k-1) = C(5+4-1,4-1) = C(8,3) $$

Now distribute the 6 blue socks into 4 drawers.

$$ n_B = C(n+k-1,k-1) = C(6+4-1, 4-1) = C(9,3) $$

The solution should be the product of the two.

$$ n_T = n_R n_B = C(8,3)\cdot C(9,3) = 4704 $$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $ C(n + k - 1, k) $? According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition)

Comment: You're distributing $n$ indistinguishable objects into $k$ distinguishable boxes, the formula for which is given by $C(n+k-1,k-1)$.

Comment: I see, but I think you substituted 4 for $ k - 1 $ in the second part of the combinations, while it should be (4 - 1).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, 4 drawers not 5.

Answer (score 0):

Polya style.

Let's make the inventory of the four drawers. A drawer may contain $0..5$ red socks and $0..6$ blue socks.

$drawer(r,b) = (1+r+r^2+...r^5) . (1+b+b^2+...b^6)$

The closet has four drawers.

$closet(r,b) = drawer(r,b)^4$

we are interested in the coefficient or $r^5b^6$ of the closet, which is $4704$.

$[r^5b^6]closet(r,b) = 4704$